# Conditional Concurrency (Mixing Concurrency with Sequentiality)

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, sequential

Greetings Overflowers,

I'm working with C# .Net 4.
I want to give priority to specific parts of my code to utilize concurrency while other parts can also do the same only if there is room (free cores), otherwise they should switch to sequential execution (in the invoker thread) rather than just being temporarily blocked.
How can I do that ? Any good recent reading on that specific issue ?
Do Parallel.Invoke(...) execute stuff sequentially in the invoker task/thread if no cores are available?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a 'free thread'.  There's only an unused core.  You can simply count them with Environment.ProcessorCount and base you threading strategy on that.  Not leveraging the ThreadPool is usually a mistake, it does a good job distributing tp threads across cores.  But it doesn't easily give you what you ask for, ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads is a constantly changing number.  Should be anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got the impression that the parallel framework handed out threads based on physical availability. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/concurrency/default.aspx

I might be thinking of the parallel extensions ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/ ), or they might be the same thing or I might be talking rubbish :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with F#, it's possible to control/configure use of concurrency from outside of your core application code.  I would expect C# Async CTP to offer similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Free threads  is a concept that exists only in the .Net thread pool. What you meant probably is free CPU resources!?

If you are declaring your own threads with new Thread() you are not bound by it.

However spawning a lot of them can slow down the process and even the OS.
That is why you should make your own thread manager to handle this.

You could check the CPU usage liek this:

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
double cpuUsage = Convert.ToDouble(cpuCounter.NextValue());
```

And then in you code use the variable to do:

```
int threadId;
if (cpuUsage > threshold) {
    DoWork();
}
else {
    threadId = YourThreadManager.Queue(DoWork);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is prioritization.  You are saying that you have two types of tasks: important tasks (which must run), and leisure tasks (that can run only when there is a free CPU and no important tasks are queued).

The simple solution is to assign a *very high* priority for important tasks, and *very low* priority for leisure tasks.  This way, you almost guarantee that most of your system's CPU resources go towards running important tasks.  However, it does *not* guarantee that your leisure tasks always run *after* all the important tasks are run.  The system may still schedule some leisure tasks onces in a while.

However, the Task Parallel Library does not allow scheduling tasks with different priorities.  You can either use [something like this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2011/01/29/how-to-schedule-task-on-different-thread-priority.aspx) or override the TPL's scheduler with a custom implementation of BlockingCollection that always dequeues the important tasks first.

One solution is to schedule your important tasks with the TPL, but manually schedule your leisure tasks on your own background thread (set to the lowest thread priority) -- and this thread runs the leisure tasks sequentially.